# Image isn't displaying/loading

Tags: html

I'm trying to put up a logo for the web page of one of our repositories. I managed to place the logo on the base html as that code is used throughout the whole site, it just calls the html fragments from the directory depending on what the user clicked in the navbar.

The problem: It displays correctly in the home page (dashboard) but when you click on the other navbar items the image converts to an icon that I usually see when an image fails to load.

this is the site: http://dir.coe.upd.edu.ph/

```
<div class="image" style="position:absolute; padding: 5px;">
        <img src="../static/css/images/logo.png" class="responsive-image">
</div>
<div style="background-color:#d07837;height:300px;width:100%;position:absolute;z-index:-10;"> </div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">

        <div>
            <h1 class="page-title">{% block page_title %}{% endblock page_title %}</h1>
        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span12 well content-box">

                {% block body %}{% endblock body %}
            </div>                
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm still currently editing the site and I noticed this problem. the site was constructed though codeigniter and bootstrap

Comment: The path is probably not correct. ../static/css/images/logo.png means go one folder back(from current), and navigate into /static/css/images/logo.png. Are your templates in the navbar on the same level as this file you are showing? If not the path will be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html are not at the same levels so your src attribute of the img tag is wrong.

This is what chrome devtools shows on the different pages.

> logo.png /static/css/images
>
> logo.png /works/static/css/images  <-- There is no image in this
>   folder. It should be in /static/css/images

One of them is not found because they are different. Try use the absolute path or change the location of your template.

Solution change your image tag to

```
<img src="/static/css/images/logo.png" class="responsive-image">
```

Comment: must be that stressed out to not see that, ugh... :) it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your image is at the location http://dir.coe.upd.edu.ph/static/css/images/logo.png

so your src attribute of image tag should be

```
<img src="/static/css/images/logo.png" class="responsive-image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on image...Hope this help[image]